# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getStandardUnit.findIndex')

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
const AddFood = (props) => {

  // DROPDOWN MENU CONST (1 - for dropdown menu, 2 - for API call, 3 - for getting the standard unit)
  const [getSelected, setSelected] = React.useState("");
  const [ingredientData, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [getStandardUnit, setStandardUnit] = React.useState(initialState);
  const initialState = [
    {key: "", standardUnit: ""},
  ]

  // QUANTITY CONST
  const [getQuantity, setQuantity] = React.useState("");

  // DATE CONST
  const [getDay, setDay] = React.useState("");
  const [getMonth, setMonth] = React.useState("");
  const [getYear, setYear] = React.useState("");

  // DROPDOWN MENU DATA
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //(async () => {
    try {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/ingredients', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        //console.log('getting data from fetch (dropdown)')
        //console.log(responseJson)
        // Store values in temporary array (newArray)
        let newArray = responseJson.map((item) => {
          return {key: item.ingredientID, value: item.name}
        })
        let newArraySU = responseJson.map((item) => {
          return {key: item.ingredientID, standardUnit: item.standardUnit}
        })
        // Set data variable
        setStandardUnit(newArraySU)
        setData(newArray)
      })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    //})
  },[])

  const dayData = [
    {key:'1',value:'01'},
  ]

  const monthData = [
    {key:'1',value:'01'},
  ]

  const yearData = [
    {key:'2023',value:'2023'},
  ]

  const onPressBack = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate('BarcodeOrManual');
  }

  const concatDate = getDay + getMonth + getYear

  // ASYNC COMPONENT TO POST DATA TO API  
  const storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/pantry', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          ingredientID: {getSelected},
          quantity: {getQuantity},
          dateExpiry: {concatDate},
          frozen: 1
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => console.log(responseJson))
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  // VALIDATION AND PASS DATA TO DATABASE
  const showAlert = () => {
    if (getSelected && getQuantity && getDay && getMonth && getYear) {

      Alert.alert (
        "Food entered successfully"
      );

      storeData();

    } else {

      Alert.alert (
        "Please fill in all the fields"
      );

    }
  }

  var index = getStandardUnit.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.key == getSelected
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingVertical: 50, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>

      {/* DROPDOWN MENU FOR FOOD */}
      <SelectList
        data={ingredientData}
        // onSelect={() => alert(selected)}
        // setSelected={setSelected}
        setSelected={setSelected}
        dropdownItemStyles={{marginHorizontal:10}}
        dropdownTextStyles={{color:'black'}}
        searchPlaceholder="Enter item"
        placeholder="Enter item"
        maxHeight={100}
      />

      {/* FOOD QUANTITY */}
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 9, marginBottom: 3, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Quantity:</Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={setQuantity}
          value={getQuantity}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <Text>{index}</Text>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>{getStandardUnit[index].standardUnit}</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
  )

}
```

I have changed the initial state for getStandardUnit from [] to initialState (as seen in the code), as well as removed an async function wrapped around the API call for // DROPDOWN MENU DATA all in aid to fix this problem I keep getting for different expressions.

The following line is what is causing the problems:

```
<Text style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>{getStandardUnit[index].standardUnit}</Text>
```

as well as the index function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting this error because you are trying to access the `initialState` variable before it is initialized.

In order for this to work, you to have initialState initialized before the line where you have the useState for `getStandardUnit` and `setStandardUnit`.

In order words, just rearrange your code to this:

```
const AddFood = (props) => {
  const initialState = [
    {key: "", standardUnit: ""},
  ]

  const [getSelected, setSelected] = React.useState("");
  const [ingredientData, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [getStandardUnit, setStandardUnit] = React.useState(initialState);
}
```